# Container is not showing up on the ui

Tags: flutter

Hello I am doing this app with flutter but I have a problem with my new UI. My containers doesn't appear in my UI. I made just the first one but I don't understand what I should add. I tried to add a SizedBox and nothing changed

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SeeAllPage extends StatefulWidget {

    @override
  _SeeAllPageState createState() => _SeeAllPageState();
}

class _SeeAllPageState extends State<SeeAllPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        
        children: [ Positioned(
              left: 16,
              top: 32,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                color: Colors.indigoAccent[700],
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              )),
             
             SingleChildScrollView(
               child: Container(
                 width: 100,
                 height: 40,
                 margin: EdgeInsets.only(right:10),
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white10,borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
               ),
             )
              
              
              ],),
    );
  }
  
  }
```

This is what I tried to acquire right now but I don't know how[image of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEaJ0.png)

Comment: have you tried pacing Positioned() after Container().

Comment: But why you use a stack here ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

You can use ListView builder if you have a dynamic number of Card. And i think you have to put the arrow in the Appbar.

[image]

```
class SeeAllPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SeeAllPageState createState() => _SeeAllPageState();
}

class _SeeAllPageState extends State<SeeAllPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20, bottom: 10),
              child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            color: Colors.indigoAccent[700],
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          Card(
                elevation: 5,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 150,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white10,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                ),
              ),
          Card(
                elevation: 5,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 150,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white10,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                ),
              ),
          Card(
                elevation: 5,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 150,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white10,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                ),
              ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```